# Update multiple vendor prefix styles in webstorm

Tags: css, webstorm, emmet

In Webstorm 10, you can insert all vendor prefix styles using built in emmet.  For instance, you type in `-border-radius` followed by the TAB key, it will automatically create the vendor specific styles for you.  Then you can type in eg. `10px` and it will apply the style to all vendor prefixes.

My question is, if I want to update the style at a later stage, is there a way to update in 1 place and have it applied to the rest?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nico is right - CSS pre-processors like Less and SASS are awesome for this type of thing - they help you to not have to repeat yourself.

If you're sticking with CSS though, WebStorm has **multi-line editing**, so one way to do this is to hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and click just before each of the `10px` values. You will spawn a new cursor at each point where you click and then you can overtype with your new value and it will change all of them.

I appreciate that's not quite as slick as when you create the multiple vendor-prefixed lines in the first place. You might just find it quicker to recreate the whole block.

Comment: Thanks.  While I do agree fully with you and @Nico, multi-line editing is what I was looking for.  I'm still getting using to working with Webstorm.  And multi-line editing was super useful when I was using sublime text.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well directly in CSS there is no quick way. However (and not specific to webstorm as I haven never tried) you could use LESS http://lesscss.org/features/.

Basically LESS is a pre-processor for CSS that you define variables in the LESS file (for instance your -border-radius property) and then when the LESS file is processed the variables are replaced with the definition. For instance

```
@border-radius: 10px;

.my-class{
   border-radius: @border-radius;
}
```

Will result as

```
.my-class{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

There are many other great features however in your exact case you may even want to use a [Parametric Mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature). These allow you to define custom styles with variables. There example is almost exactly what you are looking for such as (taken from the reference).

```
.border-radius(@radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
     -moz-border-radius: @radius;
          border-radius: @radius;
}
```

And called as:

```
#header {
  .border-radius(4px);
}
.button {
  .border-radius(6px);
}
```

Now you can use LESS many different ways and pre-process your files to css on the fly or process them as part of your deployment.

Here is a reference found for [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html)